# Identify multi-stemmed thorny shrub with alternate ovate leaves

Tags: identification, trees, thorns

Can any one identify this tree from these leaves pic

[image]?

It has thorns too. Adding more pics. I am in St. Louis MO.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you located?  Do you have a picture that shows the whole tree?  Is this a shrub or a tree?  Is there a stump in the center of that circle of stems in the background of this picture?  Are the thorns 'true thorns' or false?  Aka are they stubby little appendages that bare leaves?  Are they very sharp?  The reason I ask is that many apples have false thorns which are just stubby branches which typically bare fruit.

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: Are there berries on it? It looks a bit like a [chokecherry shrub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_virginiana).

Comment: Now we are all having some fun!  Thanks Sachin!  Thorns?  Now that you've said that or I actually read that I can see them on the trunks.  Really need to find some buds or berries or catkins!  What a variety of ID's on one question!  Just love this...Please send more pictures,  anything at all you know about this plant!

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to narrow this down without more info/pictures, but I would lean towards something in the malus (apple) or prunus(cherry) genus.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is a Wild Pear, here is a link and some photos I found. I have several around my home and tired for some time to find out what they were. 
Hope this helps.
http://www.cirrusimage.com/tree_wild_pear.htm

[Wild Pear Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtLai.jpg)